# SQL UPDATE Statement on complex select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a complex select query with many joins. It is generate from a tool. I have to update a field based on that query.

I tried to decode it but not sure that updating based on my decode is correct. Can I update the values based on the tool generated query. Like below:-

```
UPDATE F_Sales SET d_source = "XYZ" WHERE
F_Sales.customer_code in (SELECT A, B, C, D......... FROM K, L, M, N, O,P ....)
```

Comment: You could use CTE or a temp table, would make it more readable. You can then join to it to avoid IN

Comment: you can't use `IN (SELECT A, B, C, D...` as the `IN` clause can only compare to a single column if written like that. You'd need to have all the values in a single column to write it like this.

Comment: I can see it may still have leaks, as it is similar to UPDATE statement with where clause compared to a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #temp(customer_code INT)
insert into #temp SELECT A, B, C, D......... FROM K, L, M, N, O,P ....

UPDATE F_Sales SET d_source = "XYZ" 
FROM F_Sales  join #temp ON
F_Sales.customer_code = #temp.customer_code
```

Comment: however this query might fail, and I need to figure out exact scenario for one table.

Answer (score 0):

Provided one of the `A,B, ..` columns (column `D` for example) can be mapped to `F_Sales.customer_code`

```
UPDATE F_Sales SET d_source = "XYZ" 
WHERE
F_Sales.customer_code in (
  SELECT D 
  FROM ( -- untouched original query
     SELECT A, B, C, D......... FROM K, L, M, N, O,P ....) q
)
```

or

```
UPDATE F_Sales SET d_source = "XYZ" 
FROM F_Sales 
JOIN ( -- untouched original query
     SELECT A, B, C, D......... FROM K, L, M, N, O,P ....) q
ON F_Sales.customer_code = q.D
```

Probably we can make it much better if you can show the generated query